# is Sharing rules get recalcuated on deployment of Same OWD

Tags: apex, deployment, ant, sharing-rule, owd

I have one repository where i have OWD for account,contact and some other custom objects which is same as in salesforce org.
Is Sharing rules getting recalculated if I deployed the same OWD.
Please suggest.

Comment: Are you asking because that seems to be the case (or not), or because you want to make sure it does (or does not)? What behavior do you expect? Are you experiencing a problem because of the behavior? The underlying reasoning for this question would likely produce a better answer, so if you could please [edit] your question to include more information, that'd be great.

Comment: I just want to make sure it does or not,as we have a repository where plenty of objects with sharing setting needs to deployed with the same which is in org

Comment: Hi Sam, I am not too sure would OWD result sharing recalculation. Normally, the sharing rule change would recalculate the sharing. Maybe OWD and sharing rule behaves differently, but I guess OWD would be less resource consuming. Based on this doc (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=deploy_special_behavior.htm&type=5), For example, you can add a sharing rule when the org-wide default is public, and subsequently update the sharingModel. This would result in a single sharing recalculation.

Comment: or try Defer Sharing Rule Calculations as a pre-deployment step before you deploy https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_rule_recalculation.htm&type=5